# What is the synonym for "to raise the inner parts of the brows"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I'm not looking for the name of the face expression (e.g. sad, or sorry, or "inner brow raise", etc.), I'm looking for the name of the **movement** that is made. I thought maybe there was a less complicated and more appealing version of it than "to raise the inner sides of the brows"? For example, "in the pictures the guys are ... their brows". I can't really find any pics because I simply don't know what to type in in a search bar. But I remembered a couple of movie scenes, so here you go:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I found a source which suggests "eyebrows slopped outwards". Sounds weird to me :/  Can that actually be a thing? (context: "By pushing together the eyebrows and pulling up the forehead, the eyebrows can be made to slope outwards.")

EDIT 2: If I said "his eyebrows raised in (a) sorry", would that make sense and be understood? If yes, would the article before sorry be needed?

EDIT 3: Here are some more pictures I could find:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89372/discussion-on-question-by-dee-what-is-the-synonym-for-to-raise-the-inner-parts).

Answer (score 1):

You can say these people are "furrowing their brows".

Here's a [link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-make-a-particular-facial-expression) (Macmillan Dictionary) that can help.

Answer (score 1):

The term "arched brow" is often used to describe this expression. Its especially common in political speeches.

- in relation to [political speeches](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/getting-to-the-heart-of-the-voter/)
- in relation to [Bill Clinton and Ross Perot](https://www.tampabay.com/archive/1996/10/07/smart-viewers-now-expect-more-from-live-tv/) in a presidential debate.
- in relation to [William F Buckley](https://www.newschannel10.com/story/7934766/conservative-author-william-f-buckley-jr-dead-at-82/)
- in relation to [George W Bush](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/book-excerpt-mark-updegroves-republicans/story?id=51088011)

I notice the beauty industry sometimes uses the word ["inverted eyebrows"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eyebrows/comments/rdmsgx/noticed_my_eyebrows_are_uneven_when_inverted/), since it forces the eyebrows to slope in the less common direction.