# How do you describe one's making wrinkles between their eyebrows?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to describe the wrinkles between one's pair of eyebrows that the person's unconsciously making. Here are what I've come up with:

> He's making wrinkles between his eyebrows.

> He's frowning through his eyebrows.

> He's frowning with his eyebrows.

I've never used any of these lines before so I don't know which of them is natural to native speakers or if any of them convey the meaning I'm trying to express. Note that the person isn't really "frowning" and the only noticeable thing on his face is the wrinkles between his eyebrows.

Comment: This is frowning. Nothing more is necessary.

Comment: He scrunched his eyebrows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the synonym for "to raise the inner parts of the brows"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483908/what-is-the-synonym-for-to-raise-the-inner-parts-of-the-brows)

Answer (score 7):

If specifically referring to the wrinkles themselves, you could use the word, "furrow," as a verb.

> ## furrow
>
> *v*
>
> 1. make a rut, groove, or trail in (the ground or the surface of something). "gorges furrowing the deep-sea floor"
> 2. (with reference to the forehead or face) mark or be marked with lines or wrinkles caused by frowning, anxiety, or concentration. "a
>    look of concern furrowed his brow"

https://www.lexico.com/definition/Furrow

Comment: You also see [**knitting** one's brow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knit%20one%27s%20brow%2Fbrows), which is more specifically about bringing one's eyebrows closer together.

Answer (score -1):

He **puckered** his eyebrows.

> : to draw or cause to draw up into folds or wrinkles

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pucker#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20draw%20or%20cause%20to,made%20me%20pucker%20my%20lips.)

This is possible but the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puckered+eyebrows%2C+furrowed+eyebrows&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpuckered%20eyebrows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfurrowed%20eyebrows%3B%2Cc0) shows it is  not much used.